# Upgrade to ESAPI-2.5.0.0

Tags: java, spring-security, esapi

I am recently moved to ESAPi-2.5.0.0 so that blackduck doesnt complain about log4j. However i am getting the below error.

```
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Encoder class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder) CTOR threw exception.
        at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:129)
        at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.encoder(ESAPI.java:101)
        at 

        Caused by:
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:86)
            ... 5 more

            Caused by:
            org.owasp.esapi.errors.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory LogFactory class (org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory) must be in class path.
                at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:108)
                at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.logFactory(ESAPI.java:139)
                at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.getLogger(ESAPI.java:155)
```

`Below are my ESAPI.prperties:`
`ESAPI.AccessControl=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultAccessController`

## `FileBasedAuthenticator requires users.txt file in .esapi directory`

`ESAPI.Authenticator=org.owasp.esapi.reference.FileBasedAuthenticator`
`ESAPI.Encoder=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder`
`ESAPI.Encryptor=org.owasp.esapi.reference.crypto.JavaEncryptor`

`ESAPI.Executor=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultExecutor`
`ESAPI.HTTPUtilities=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultHTTPUtilities`
`ESAPI.IntrusionDetector=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultIntrusionDetector`

## ``` Log4JFactory Requires log4j.xml or log4j.properties in classpath - ``http://www.laliluna.de/log4j-tutorial.html ```

`ESAPI.Logger=org.owasp.esapi.reference.JavaLogFactory`
`ESAPI.Randomizer=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultRandomizer`
`ESAPI.Validator=org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator`

`any help would be highly appreciated.`

Tried Upgrading to ESAPI-2.5.0.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/742609/kevin-w-wall : @kevin-w-wall, I tried few of your suggestions but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to make a guess, it looks as though your **ESAPI.properties** file has the `ESAPI.Logger` property still set to `org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory`. Log4J support was removed from ESAPI in release 2.5.0.0 so that class was removed with it. (It had been deprecated for just over 2 years before we removed it.) And that class had been renamed to `org.owasp.esapi.logging.log4j.Log4JLogFactory` at least as far back as 2.3.0.0.

But since you noted that you had set it to ESAPI.Logger to use JUL, it seems likely that you are not picking up the ESAPI.properties file that you think you are picking up because the last 'caused by' in the exception stack trace clearly shows `org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogFactory` as what is giving the ClassNotFoundError. (Or else you are using that class somewhere in your code.)

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the info. I am able to make it work. I had to add few more properties :Logger.ApplicationName=
Logger.UserInfo=
Logger.ClientInfo=
Logger.LogApplicationName=
Logger.LogServerIP=
Logger.LogEncodingRequired= .

Comment: @user2918699 Where did you add the properties information? I'm using a jar that is using the ESAPI.

Comment: @iLearn - By default, those additional properties should be placed in the file "esapi-java-logging.properties" which will be in the esapi-<version>-configuration.jar file that you downloaded from https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/releases